# Having issue with number of taps in UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer, tvos, apple-tv

I am trying to run a method by 2 times `tapping` on tv remote, consider tapping **not** clicking, but the touch surface does't recognize the taps. Instead, clicking two times runs the `doubleTapping` method.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    doubleTap.allowedTouchTypes =@[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UITouchTypeIndirect]];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];



- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        // handling code
        NSLog(@"2 times");
    }
}
```

I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was forgot to mention the `UIPressType` value ,  now due to position of remote's surface (Up / Down / Right / Left) you can now detect user's tap direction and add `numberOfTapsRequired` to the action :

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [tapGestureRecognizer setAllowedPressTypes:@[@(UIPressTypeLeftArrow)]];
    [tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```